# Can you cast a spell you know from one class as if it was a spell from another?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing

Bards can use a musical instrument as a spellcasting focus for bard spells.

If I have levels in both the Bard and Sorcerer classes, a musical instrument to use as a spellcasting focus, no access to an arcane focus, and a known Sorcerer spell that also appears on the Bard spell list but needs a material component (such as Invisibility), can I cast the Sorcerer spell as if it was a Bard spell? Since it is a Bard spell, I know it, and I have a spellcasting focus for it.

Comment: If you feel the question I've linked is not the same as your own, feel free to explain what feels left out

Comment: Related: [If I multiclass into 2 or more spellcasting classes, how do I determine my known/prepared spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151000/if-i-multiclass-into-2-or-more-spellcasting-classes-how-do-i-determine-my-known)