# Wizard/Arcane Trickster learning 2nd level spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, multi-classing, rogue

I am a 3rd level Rogue/Arcane Trickster considering multiclassing into a Wizard. I understand, however, that this may cause some issues with my higher level spells and just want to make sure I don't lose out on them.

To clarify, I **do** understand how many spell slots I have, hence this is not a duplicate:

> **Spell Slots.** You determine your available spell slots by adding
> together all your levels... - *PHB, p164*

What I am asking is when will I learn 2nd level spells? Particularly noting that I will have two 2nd level spell slots at AT 3/Wiz 2. However:

> You determine what spells you know and can
> prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed
> member of that class. - *PHB, p164*

As I understand from doing a bit of reading around the forum, this means that even though together I have the slots of a level 3 Wizard (Rogue AT levels being worth 1/3 a wizard level) I will not be considered a level 3 caster for either of my classes. Is that correct?

In addition, am I correct assuming I will have to reach Rogue 7 or Wizard 3 before I unlock any level 2 spells? (I presume this because in their respective spell tables, this is when each class gains level 2 spells.)

Comment: Your question seems like a duplicate of this broader Q&A: [If I multiclass into 2 or more spellcasting classes, how do I determine my known/prepared spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151000/33569) - Does the answer to that question address the answer to yours? (If not, please edit your question to clarify how it's not already addressed by that Q&A.)

Comment: Perfect, thank you for pointing that out! I will delete my question.

Comment: No need to delete it - it's fine to just close it as a duplicate, but leave it up as a "signpost" pointing to the general question :)